# Show that $d_g$ is a metric on $l^1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

On the space $l^1$ of complex valued sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\sum|x_n|<\infty$, define for $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$, $y=(y_1,y_2,\cdots)$ the metric $d_f$ by
$$d_g(x,y)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}.$$
Show that $d_g$ is a metric on $l^1$.

So we would go through the four properties of a metric:

1.) Moduli suggests non-negativity

2.) If $d_g(x,y) =0$, then $\sum^\infty_{n=1}0=0$ and if $x_n, y_n =0$ then $\sum^\infty_{n=1}0$ would mean that $d_g(x,y) =0$. Thus $d_g(x,y) =0 \Leftrightarrow x_n, y_n =0$

3.) Symmetry property is trivial

4.) Triangle inequality. Here is where I get stuck. I think we would say
$$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\leq \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|} + \frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}.$$
And this gives us $d_g(x,y)\leq d_g(x,z)+d_g(z,y)$. Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

How to show the inequality: consider $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$. Since, $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$, it is strictly increasing in $x$ and strictly concave. Therefore, $f(x+y)-f(y)$ is strictly decreasing in $y$. Hence, $f(x+y)-f(y)\le f(x+0)-f(0)=f(x)$. Now, $f(|x-z|)+f(|y-z|)\ge f(|x-z|+|y-z|)\ge f(|x-y|)$.

---

About the metric. First, you need

0) $d_g(x,y)$ is well defined:

$$d_g(x,y)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}\le \sum^\infty_{n=1}|x_n|+|y_n|<\infty.$$

1) Correct.

2) $d_g(x,y)=0\iff \forall n: |x_n-y_n|=0\iff \forall n: x_n=y_n.$

3) Is correct, since $|x_n-y_n|=|y_n-x_n|$.

4) If you are given a metric space with topology $d$ then the metric given by

$$d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$$

is also a metric, and, in fact, it is equivalent to $d$. Hence, $\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ equivalent to the usual metric $|x-y|$, and the inequality you are trying to prove is correct (I proved it for you at the top).